# How to access boolean array Java

Tags: java

I have the following constructor which defines a `board` and checks if any of the three `JButton`s have been clicked:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(500, this);

private boolean[][] board;
private boolean isActive = true;
private int height;
private int width;
private int multiplier = 40;

JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
public Board(boolean[][] board) {
    this.board = board;
    height = board.length;
    width = board[0].length;
    setBackground(Color.black);
    button1 = new JButton("Stop");
    add(button1);
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isActive = !isActive;
            button1.setText(isActive ? "Stop" : "Start");
        }
    });
    button2 = new JButton("Random");
    add(button2);
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            this.board = randomBoard();
        }
    });
    button3 = new JButton("Clear");
    add(button3);
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            this.board = clearBoard();
        }
    });
}
```

But it returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    board cannot be resolved or is not a field
    board cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Why is this? How do I access `this.board` in the constructor?

Comment: Where have you defined `board`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by you trying to access `this.board` inside the anonymous inner classes. Since there is no `board` field defined, that causes an error.

For example this:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.board = randomBoard();
    }
});
```

In order to be able to use the `board` variable inside your anonymous inner classes you either need to remove `this` or use something like `Board.this.board` (if you want to be more explicit).

Comment: From a non-static inner class (even an anonymous one) you can just access the member variables of the outer class, as long as you remove `this` (so just use `board = randomBoard();`)

Comment: @Heuster: This only works when the board parameter would be final. But then he could not assign a value to it.

Comment: @mszalbach I don't think fields need to be final. final is only for the case of local variables so that they are not popped out of stack when the method exists.

Comment: @Cemre: Its not the field which needs to be final but the parameter passed into the constructor. Because this is what you want to access when you just remove the this before board. To access the field of Board it only helps to use Board.this.board.

Comment: @mszalbach For the case of passing as a parameter, yes you probably need to make it final. But in this case it works to just remove `this`  since there is no other `board` variable the anonymous inner class defines. You dont *have to* use `Board.this.board`. I just tested to make sure.

Comment: @Cemre. Yeah I tested too and get the compile error: "java: Board.java:49: local variable board is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final". And yes there are two board variables, the one as member variable of the class Board and the parameter of the board constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.board = randomBoard();
    }
});
```

your `button2` is a `JButton`, and it doesn't have a `board` field.  Don't access it with `this.board`.  Find another way to access `board`.

---

The fast and dirty way to do it would be to make `board` static, but I'm sure that `JButton` has a way for you to specify a parent(your board class), and access the `board` field that way.

After a quick look at [The documentation for JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), I've found a [getParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) method.  I'd start with that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Board.this.board = randomBoard();
```

The problem is `this` related to the class ActionListener which did not have a board variable. However with `Board.this` you specify that you mean the board member of the Board class. This is the syntax you need to use for nested classes to access the variables of the outer class.

Answer (score -1):

As others and the compiler said, you don't have a field (which is an [instance member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable)), but only a [local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) board, which goes out of scope as soon as constructor exits.